# Azure B2C force login after password reset sub journey

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

we're using password reset sub-journey as described here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#self-service-password-reset-recommended).

When using this, a user is automatically logged upon successful password reset flow. We want to stop that and redirect user to sign-in page after successful password reset.

How can we achieve this, here is what main journey looks like:

```
    <UserJourney Id="SignIn">
          <OrchestrationSteps>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signin">
              <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
                <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
              </ClaimsProviderSelections>
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>objectId</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPasswordExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                  <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
              <JourneyList>
                <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="PasswordReset" />
              </JourneyList>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>.....
------------------------------------------------------
    <SubJourney Id="PasswordReset" Type="Call">
          <OrchestrationSteps>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingLogonName" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="VerifyEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyEmail" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
          </OrchestrationSteps>
```

Comment: Why you were not happy with auto login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

A simple solution (might not be ideal) is to block the user using a self asserted page without cancel / continue buttons as the last step in password reset sub journey. That way the user never gets a jwt token.
You could have some text in the self asserted page saying something like 'Your password has been reset successfully. Please login again.' You can also provide login url in the same page so that user can navigate to it or redirect after a delay using javascript.

Example:

```xml
 <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-PasswordResetBlockPage">
    <DisplayName>Show Block message</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
        <Item Key="AllowGenerationOfClaimsWithNullValues">true</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.showContinueButton">false</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.showCancelButton">false</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="responseMsg" DefaultValue="Your password has been reset successfully. Please login again with your new credentials." AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="responseMsg" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

```xml
<ClaimType Id="responseMsg">
    <DisplayName>Information</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <AdminHelpText>A claim responsible for holding response messages to send to the relying party</AdminHelpText>
    <UserHelpText>A claim responsible for holding response messages to send to the relying party</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

**Option 2**
Have the orchestration steps for sign in again after password reset. Skip it if  password reset has not been done.

**Note**: Make sure you test extensively, especially with SSO flows to make sure everything works as expected.