# Azure Ad B2C auto signin after signup/resetpassword

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c

In my .net6 razor pages web application, I could see signin, signout, signup and reset password policies working perfectly fine. But after successful execution of a policy journey, say signup or reset password, the web app User.Identity.IsAuthenticated remains true and it shows as the user is logged in and I have to manually click signout in the page to signout the user. Can anyone please help on this issue? I have default configuration in program.cs for MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication.

Comment: Why you do not like auto-signin after sign-up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make user return on login page after sign-up in Azure AD B2C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141778/how-to-make-user-return-on-login-page-after-sign-up-in-azure-ad-b2c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behaviour.

You are signed in until either the session expires or you manually sign out.

Comment: So the recommended way is to call the signout method everytime after signup/reset password to prevent auto signin? Also is there any Microsoft documentation that confirms the same?

Comment: The default behaviour for any IDP is that once you have signed in you remain signed in until either you manually sign-out or the admin revokes the session or your session expires (which forces a new sign in). Not sure what you mean by auto-signin?

Comment: Yes but my question isn't about signin policy. When I either signup/reset password, due to jwt tokens returned from the signup/reset policy, web app shows that the user is signed in. The expectation is to not have the user signed in after signup journey. Is there any work around for this scenario? The below question has a workaround provided. But am not sure if it is the right way to do it. Could you please check and confirm? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72342813/azure-b2c-force-login-after-password-reset-sub-journey/73415118?noredirect=1#comment129648770_73415118

Comment: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/password-reset-only